# How to solve dynamic memory allocation error in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to dynamically allocate memory for user input. When I try to run the program with valgrind, I get a few errors with memory allocation. Here's the message:

```
==796==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==796==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==796==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==796==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==796==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

Here's what the valgrind console outputs[image]:

Here's **main.c**:

```
#include "functions.h"

int main(void) {
    clear();
    void (*funcptr)(void);
    int option;

    printf("=========================================Login or Create Account=========================================\n\n");
    while(1) {
        printf("Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?\n>>> ");
        option = fgetc(stdin);
        cleanStdinBuffer();

        switch (option) {
            case '1':
                funcptr = create_account;
                break;

            case '2':
                funcptr = login;
                break;

            default:
                printf("\033[0;31m[ERROR] Invalid input. Please choose a valid option");
                fflush(stdout);
                print_dots(3);
                printf("\n\033[0m");
                continue;
            }

        break;
        }
    funcptr();
    return 0;
}
```

The error happens when I try to create a bank account. I haven't tried login yet, however. code for the `create account` function in **functions.h**:

```
void create_account() {
    clear();
    char *username;
    char *password;
printf("=========================================Create Account=========================================\n");
    printf("Enter a username: ");
    username = strmalloc(&username);
    printf("Enter a password: ");
    password = strmalloc(&password);

    printf("%s is your username and %s is your password", username, password);
}
```

And here is my code for the function to dynamically allocate memory which is also in **functions.h**:

```
char *strmalloc(char **string) {
    char *tmp = NULL;
    size_t size = 0, index = 0;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (size <= index) {
            size += 1;
            tmp = realloc(*string, size);
            if (!tmp) {
                free(*string);
                string = NULL;
                break;
            }
            *string = tmp;
        }
        (*string)[index++] = ch;
    }
    return *string;
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: How do you call `strmalloc`? Show a [mcve]..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and the full and complete Valgrind output from that example.

Comment: @shrewmouse `0` is equivalent to a null pointer. And when passed a null pointer `free` does nothing. It's okay to pass a null pointer to `free`.

Comment: @shrewmouse `free(NULL);` is allowed.

Comment: `string = NULL;` `break;` `return *string;` is a null pointer defereference. I think you meant `*string = NULL;`.

Comment: The `*string` is never null-terminated.

Comment: I've made edits to the post everyone. Please see them and tell me if it's still what you're thinking

Comment: `username` and `password` variables have not been initialized to `NULL` before the calls `strmalloc(&username);` and `strmalloc(&password);`, so the `realloc(*string, size);` is passing a junk pointer value to `realloc`. Perhaps `strmalloc` should intially set `*string = NULL;`?

Comment: `username` is not initialized.  `realloc( uninitialized_variable )` goes boom.

Comment: Does `strmalloc` need both a parameter and a return value? One of them is redundant.

Comment: Thank you @WilliamPursell for the solution. That removed the error message

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you as well for the solution. Also, I need both of them because I'm pretty much making a replica of `scanf` or `gets` or one of those functions so that I can set the exact size for the string and return it so that it gets stored in the variable

Comment: Simply just drop mixing dynamic memory and user input. Grab user input as a string with `fgets` and store it in a 256 byte large buffer. On systems supporting heap allocation, there is no sound reason why you can't.

Comment: Even if we have a screenshot of the IDE's translation of Valgrinds messages, it's not the same as being able to read the text itself. Not only is it not possible to copy-paste anything from an image, it's also impossible to search in for specific text as well as it's impossible for screen-readers to read it. Please don't post images of what is basically text output, copy-paste the actual text as text instead.

Comment: By the way, your `strmalloc` function doesn't create a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated and wrong.

1. the string is not NUL termminated
2. you're reallocing the string that pas been passed to the function. You only can reallocate something that has been returned via `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`.
3. you don't need to pass the address of the string to `strmalloc`. Just return the newly allocated string. This automatically eliminates the bug at item 2.

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strmalloc(void) {
  char* string = malloc(1);
  if (!string)
    return NULL;

  size_t size = 0, index = 0;
  int ch;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    if (size <= index) {
      size += 1;
      char *temp = realloc(string, size + 1);   // + 1 for the NUL string terminator
      if (!temp) {
        free(string);
        return NULL;          // realloc failed return NULL straight away
      }
      string = temp;
    }
    string[index++] = ch;
  }

  string[index] = 0;          // NUL terminator
  return string;
}

int main()
{
  char* x = strmalloc();
  printf("x = %s\n", x);
  free(x);
}
```

Comment: @IanAbbott should be perfect now.